# What is the fast way to sort

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

### Problem Description

I'm writing Android application which is working with big data, I have database (15 mb) and my application shows data from it. I have a queries which are get data from database already sorted for example alphabetic or depending on some parameters which I have provided.

### Question

As I store data in the Array and then show it to user I want to know what is the fast way to sort data, while making a query or just put data in array and then sort it?

Comment: 15m != big data. 15m is a configuration table in big data :-)

Comment: why don't you try both ways and tell us the results? I think that it would be better for you to reach by yourself to a conclusion and ask on this site how to optimize the sort...

Comment: @BudaGavril sure I will try to do that and let you know.

Comment: so you want to sort a column which you get when you  query the Database ?

Comment: Have the database do it, much simpler, and at least as fast as anything you can come up with.

Comment: Just use ORDER BY. It's surely faster than sorting an array.

Comment: Its going to depend on your particular set up, eg if your query has lots of where clauses and joins on it and only returns a few rows then sorting in Java might be quicker. On the other hand, if you are just returning all the rows in a large table sorted by an indexed column then sorting in the DB might be faster.

Comment: @matthelliwell here is one of my queries select CompanyInfo._id, CompanyInfo.name_en, ContactInfo.telephones, ContactInfo.location, CompanyInfo.websites, ContactInfo.address_en, ContactInfo.location, ContactInfo.position, TopFirmsByCode.Level, ContactInfo.name_en from CompanyInfo, ContactInfo, TopFirmsByCode where CompanyInfo._id=TopFirmsByCode.RegNo AND CompanyInfo._id=ContactInfo._id AND TopFirmsByCode.Code = '458' order by TopFirmsByCode.Level ASC, CompanyInfo.rating_ordering_en ASC

Comment: @matthelliwell I think it is quit big, what do you think ?

Comment: Whilst there are a few different columns selected, there are few joins so assuming you've got your indexes set up correctly I'd expect that to run quickly. So personally I'd probably leave the sorting in the DB unless I see a particular problem. But the only way to be sure is to measure the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am also faced this situation in my application. i resolved performance by using following way.

- First i created **index** on my table based on primary key.
- Then i used **order by** to sort the elements.
- To search it in local i kept total content in  one **object** , then perform search on that object.

If you use these surly you will improve performance **200 %**.